# python yagmail table extra <td> tags in table

Tags: python-2.7, yagmail

I'm using yagmail with python 2.7 to email a table.

```
yag = yagmail.SMTP(config.SENDER_UNAME, config.SENDER_PW)
recipient="<email>"
subject= "hello"
body="hi"
html_doc="""<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><TABLE cellpadding="4"  border="1" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;border-collapse:collapse;" >                         
  <COL width="100px">                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <COL width="100px">                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <COL width="100px">                                                                                                                                                                                       
 <TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <TH>product</TH>                                                                                                                                                                                          
  <TH># orders</TH>                                                                                                                                                                                         
  <TH>revenue</TH>                                                                                                                                                                                          
 </TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 <TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <TD align="left">Type 1</TD>                                                                                                                                                                              
  <TD align="left">14</TD>                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <TD align="left">730.5</TD>                                                                                                                                                                               
 </TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 <TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <TD align="left">Type 2</TD>                                                                                                                                                                              
  <TD align="left">18</TD>                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <TD align="left">1759.3</TD>                                                                                                                                                                              
 </TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 <TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <TD align="left">total</TD>                                                                                                                                                                               
  <TD align="left">32</TD>                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <TD align="left">2489.8</TD>                                                                                                                                                                              
 </TR>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</TABLE></body></html>"""

result =yag.send(recipient,subject, [body,html_doc],headers={"From":config.SENDER_FROM})
```

But in the email that gets sent the table looks like this, with extra cells and rows added. How can I prevent that from happening?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more code? Just copying the html and sending through yagmail actually works perfectly fine for me. It works as `contents=""" your text """"` as well as when you point to a file with those contents.

Comment: @PascalvKooten maybe it's to do with the contents including a body also?

Comment: I tried that, didn't happen. contents = [txt, html, txt]

Comment: you're right - when I look at the raw content of the email, the html is fine. Somehow gets added by the web client (both gmail and inbox)

Comment: The doctype string is the problem. It works even without html and body tags btw, but adding the DOCTYPE is what causes the trouble. Note that that is obviously an error on yagmail's part.

Comment: even without the doctype string, I get this issue. If I paste the html in [https://putsmail.com](putsmail) the table renders correctly. There it's sent as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 / Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`. The base64 which yagmail sends decodes to the right html (no extra rows) but for some reason gmail ads these rows after decoding. Any idea how to work around that?